# Mixed Binary Quadratic Programming Quadratically Constrained

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, discrete-optimization, quadratic-programming, qcqp, binary-programming

I would like to find an algorithm to find the optimal (or a close approximation) of the minimum of $f(X,Y)$:
$$
f(X,Y)=\sum^N_{i=1}{x_it_i}+\sum^N_{i=1}{x_iy_ir_i}\\
\begin{align}
s.t &&x_i \in \{0,1\} \tag 1\\
&&t_i \ge 0 \tag 2\\
&&A.X = b \tag 3\\
&&C_0-\sum^k_{i=1}{x_id_i}+\sum^{k-1}_{i=1}{x_iy_ir_i}\ge0 \tag 4\\
&&\sum^k_{i=1}{x_id_i}-\sum^k_{i=1}{x_iy_ir_i}\ge0 \tag 5
\end{align}
$$
The constants:
$$
\begin{align}
C_0&&=&&consts \\
R &&=&& \{r_1,..., r_N\} \\
D &&=&& \{d_1,..., d_N\} \\
T &&=&& \{t_1,..., t_N\} \\
B &&=&& \{b_1,..., b_M\}
\end{align}
$$
The constraint (4) & (5) exist in N version $k={1,2,...,N}$.
I would to find an algorithm, which I can implement my self without buying an expensive CPLEX or Gurobi, I need something I can implement my self.

Ideas:

- The constraints (2), (4) & (5) can be reframed as Log-Barrier
- The constraint (1) can be rewritten as $x_i^2-x_i=0$
- The objective function and the constraints (4) & (5) can be rewritten in a quadratic form
- Can we solve this problem with GD, with Newton Method/Lagrangian Multiplier?

Thanks for any ideas/clues.

Best

Comment: It depends; are you trying to find exact minima? How large is your program? Depending on your answers, rewriting this as an unconstrained minimization problem using an Augmented Lagrangian method, vs. using branch-and-bound (even though the problem is non-convex as stated, so getting a good lower bound might be challenging—it seems that it can be rewritten as an SDP with rank constraints, and these can be relaxed), etc.

Comment: Yes I try to find the exact minima (if it's too hard approximate it).
All constraints are equally important.
N is about 1K to 10K and M is about N/10.
I tried to not use branch&bound/cut methods (due to the difficulties to implements).
I'm not familliar with SDP and less with Rank Constraints.
My intuition is this problem should be able to be rewritten as unconstrained minimization problem as you said. Did you have some clue about Augmented Lagrangian Method in this case (my test wasn't very fructuous).

Comment: What are the decision variables? If only $x$ and $y$, you can linearize the products $x_i y_i$.. You would end up with a linear MIP (solvers readily available).

Comment: I'm looking for a solution I can implement my self.
$x_i$ are my selector.